# Bring to Front event in Winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application that has 3 attached forms. I have set it all Top Most, so every form will look like the extension of parent form. Now users doensn't want it to be on top. When I set the TopMost to false, the forms seems to be separated.  I want to bring the all the forms to front, if any of these forms come on top (by clicking, clicking on the taskbar icon, or even using ALT TAB). I think, if there was a bring to front event, that will solve my issue.

Comment: I think your abusing `TopMost` completely, you shouldn't ever need to set them to top most, just set the dialogs parent instead

Comment: The TopMost property gets abused too much.  It certainly isn't a cure for what you are complaining about, it doesn't solve a Z-ordering problem.

What you are looking for is an *owned* window.  It is always on top of its owner, it minimizes along with its owner.  You already know them well, the various tool windows inside Visual Studio are owned windows.

You create an owned window by using the Show(owner) overload to display it.  Or by setting the Owner property explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions friends... Now, I get the clue..

Answer (score 0):

In a **Windows WinForm** application program, when the user brings a form into the topmost layer on the screen, we can make other forms in the same application program to come to the foremost layer automatically. This is achieved simply by setting the **Winform** "Owner" property. The following example demonstrate this:

Suppose we have a mainform, and two other forms

`mainForm`
`otherForm1`
`otherForm2`

In the program code, set the Owner property

`otherForm1.Owner = mainForm;`

`otherForm2.Owner = mainForm;`

Now, whenever `mainForm` is brought to the front, `otherForm1` `otherForm2` will pop to the front. You may also consider the followings in addition:

`otherForm1.ShowInTaskBar = False;`

`otherForm2.ShowInTaskBar = False;`

The group of three forms share a single icon on the taskbar.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the parent in the ctor of every child form:

```
ChildForm frm = new ChildForm(parentForm);
```

Try to use Win32-functions to hack the foreground behavior:

```
public static class User32
{
    public const int SW_HIDE = 0;
    public const int SW_SHOW = 5;
    public const int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;
    public const int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;
    public const int SW_RESTORE = 9;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool AllowSetForegroundWindow(uint dwProcessId);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
}

User32.AllowSetForegroundWindow((uint)Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
User32.SetForegroundWindow(Handle);
User32.ShowWindow(Handle, User32.SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```